# Linear Algebra Co-ordinate System transformation

Tags: c++, image-processing, linear-algebra, point-clouds

It is very easy about the matrix transformation but I could get any appropriate explanation on the web.

I have a 3D cloud point data having position vector `[x,y,z]` and normal vector `n=[a,b,c]` for every location. now I want to transform it into different coordinate system considering a specific point as origin `[0,0,0]` and its normal vector as `Z axis`, then take two random different orthogonal vectors as other axes. For this, I simply assume one orthogonal vector to be `T=[0, -n[2], n[1]]` and then normalize this one. To get another orthogonal vector, I simply cross product this with the normal`b= n.cross(t)`

Now I want to map other points and normals in terms of this coordinate system.

As far I know the normal vectors can be put into this new coordinate system using transformation matrix

```
tx ty tz 0
bx by bz 0
nx ny nz 0
0  0  0  1
```

now simply normal vectors can be multiplied to get into the new coordinate system.`normals in new coordinate sytem=T*n`
but I don't understand how to map the position vector of other points into this new coordinate system.?

Answer (score 0):

As you described it, your transformation is a pure rotation relative to the origin, hence points and normals will transform the same; that is, you can use the same matrix for both.

Note that for a general invertible affine mapping `x -> Lx+t`, if you want to preserve orthonormality, normals will transform as `n -> normalize(transpose(inverse(L)) n)` instead (but, this may not be enough depending on the nature of the transformation...).

Comment: Will there be any translation component as well for those position vectors and normal vectors in above situation? My intention is to pick any position vector in a pool of position vector and term it as an origin and its normal as the z-axis.Will there be any translation component if I want to describe other left out position and normal vector in terms of this coordinate system or will there be the only rotational transformation?

Comment: @user90 the linear part of the transformation is the same (ie the rotation to the new coordinates); of course, points will need to be translated ...